# Change route after submit form in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous

I am new in react. I write react with typescript without redux.
In my sample project i want after submit form, change route, but i can not do this. following code is my try. how can I change route in fetch then function? why this value is undefined!

```
import * as React from 'react';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { ReactRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface Props {router?: ReactRouter.History.History;}

interface State {name: string;}

export class CreateItem extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    private input: HTMLInputElement;

    constructor(props: Props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {name: ""};

        this.input = null;
    }

    public render(){

        return <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form-horizontal">
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="col-sm-2 control-label">Date</label>
                <div className="col-sm-5">
                    <input name="name" type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange} className="form-control">
                    </input>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default" disabled={!this.state.name}>ADD</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>;
    }

    private handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {

        event.preventDefault();

        if (this.state.name) {

            var form = new FormData();

            form.append('name', name);

            fetch('/api/SampleData/', { method: 'POST', body: form })
                .then(function (res) {
                    this.props.history.push('/fetchdata');// **this code not work**
                });

            this.setState({
                name: ""
            });
        }
    }

    private handleInputChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {

        const target = event.target;
        const name = target["name"];

        this.setState({
            [name]: (event as any).target.value
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors, like `cannot read property history of undefined`?

Comment: this property is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably late but anyway. Try to use the arrow function to get correct `this`

```
.then(res => {
  this.props.history.push('/fetchdata');
});
```

Comment: I used your suggested code but throw this error TS2339: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<Props>'

Comment: @MohammadAkbari the `history` property is absent cause you probably use the 'react-router' in a wrong way. Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the React Router in the wrong way. Here it is, how using it.

styles comes from MaterialUI.

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles
  ({})

interface IState
{}

interface IProps
{}

class Home extends React.Component<IProps & WithStyles<typeof styles> & RouteComponentProps<{}>, IState>
{   
    constructor(props: IProps & WithStyles<typeof styles> & RouteComponentProps<{}>)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state =
        {
        }
    }
}
```

to navigate use: this.props.history.push(`your route goes here`);